# Parse JSON into Oracle table using PL/SQL

Tags: sql, json, plsql, oracle11g

I have created the following script in order to read data from Mobile App DB (which is based on MongoDB) from Oracle SQL Developer:

```
DECLARE
  l_param_list     VARCHAR2(512);

  l_http_request   UTL_HTTP.req;
  l_http_response  UTL_HTTP.resp;

  l_response_text  VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN

  -- service's input parameters

  -- preparing Request...
  l_http_request := UTL_HTTP.begin_request ('https://api.appery.io/rest/1/db/collections/Photos?where=%7B%22Oracle_Flag%22%3A%22Y%22%7D'
                                          , 'GET'
                                          , 'HTTP/1.1');

  -- ...set header's attributes
  UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'X-Appery-Database-Id', '53f2dac5e4b02cca64021dbe');
  --UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Length', LENGTH(l_param_list));

  -- ...set input parameters
 -- UTL_HTTP.write_text(l_http_request, l_param_list);

  -- get Response and obtain received value
  l_http_response := UTL_HTTP.get_response(l_http_request);

  UTL_HTTP.read_text(l_http_response, l_response_text);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_response_text);
  insert into appery values(l_response_text);
  -- finalizing
  UTL_HTTP.end_response(l_http_response);


EXCEPTION
  WHEN UTL_HTTP.end_of_body 
    THEN UTL_HTTP.end_response(l_http_response);  
END;
/
```

The response *(l_response_text)* is a JSON-like string. For example:

```
[{"Postcode":"47100","OutletCode":"128039251","MobileNumber":"0123071303","_createdAt":"2014-11-10 06:12:49.837","_updatedAt":"2014-11-10 06:12:49.837"}, {"Postcode":"32100","OutletCode":"118034251", ..... ]
```

The code works fine, and inserts the response into one column-table called *appery*. However, I need to parse this response such that each array goes into into its specific column in a table called *appery_test*. The table *appery_test* has a number of columns same as the number of JSON pairs and in the same order.

I searched and I found most of the results about parsing Oracle table into JSON and not the opposite. I found, though, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985841/work-with-json-in-oracle) link which is somewhat similar to my issue. However, the suggested library in the answer does not have any example on how to use it to insert JSON into conventional table using PL/SQL.

**N.B.:** I'm using 11g and not 12c. So the [built in](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7535/work-with-json-in-oracle) functions are not available for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I used [PL/JSON library](https://sourceforge.net/p/pljson/wiki/Home/). Specifically, JSON_EXT package functions in order to parse it.

The following script inspired by Oracle Community answer worked for me

```
DECLARE
  l_param_list     VARCHAR2(512);

  l_http_request   UTL_HTTP.req;
  l_http_response  UTL_HTTP.resp;

  l_response_text  VARCHAR2(32767);

l_list json_list;
A_id           VARCHAR2(200);
UserId         VARCHAR2(100);
UserName       VARCHAR2(100);
OutletCode     VARCHAR2(100);
OutletName     VARCHAR2(100);
MobileNumber   VARCHAR2(100);
PhoneNumber    VARCHAR2(100);
Address        VARCHAR2(100);
City           VARCHAR2(100);
State          VARCHAR2(100);
Postcode       VARCHAR2(100);
Email          VARCHAR2(100);
UpdateCount    VARCHAR2(100);
loginCount     VARCHAR2(100);
ReferencePhoto VARCHAR2(100);
Updates        VARCHAR2(100);
AccountLocked  VARCHAR2(100);
Oracle_Flag    VARCHAR2(100);
acl            VARCHAR2(100);


BEGIN

  -- service's input parameters

  -- preparing Request...
  l_http_request := UTL_HTTP.begin_request('https://api.appery.io/rest/1/db/collections/Outlet_Details?where=%7B%22Oracle_Flag%22%3A%22Y%22%7D'
                                          , 'GET'
                                          , 'HTTP/1.1');

  -- ...set header's attributes
  UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'X-Appery-Database-Id', '53f2dac5e4b02cca64021dbe');
  --UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Length', LENGTH(l_param_list));

  -- ...set input parameters
 -- UTL_HTTP.write_text(l_http_request, l_param_list);

  -- get Response and obtain received value
  l_http_response := UTL_HTTP.get_response(l_http_request);

  UTL_HTTP.read_text(l_http_response, l_response_text);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_response_text);
  l_list := json_list(l_response_text);

FOR i IN 1..l_list.count
LOOP
  A_id           := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'_id');
  UserId         := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'UserId');
  UserName       := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'UserName');
  OutletCode     := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'OutletCode');
  OutletName     := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'OutletName');
  MobileNumber   := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'MobileNumber');
  PhoneNumber    := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'PhoneNumber');
  Address        := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'Address');
  City           := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'City');
  State          := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'State');
  Postcode       := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'Postcode');
  Email          := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'Email');
  UpdateCount    := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'UpdateCount');
  loginCount     := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'loginCount');
  ReferencePhoto := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'ReferencePhoto');
  Updates        := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'Updates');
  AccountLocked  := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'AccountLocked');
  Oracle_Flag    := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'Oracle_Flag');
  acl            := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'acl');


insert .....
```

Notice that *json_ext.get_string* retuns only VARCHAR2 limited to 32767 max. In order to use the same package with larger json_list and json_values (>32KB) check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27142161/store-big-json-files-into-oracle-db/27142469#27142469).

If you have APEX 5.0 and above, better option and much better performance via [APEX_JSON](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_json.htm#AEAPI29635) package. See @[Olafur Tryggvason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32287823/2153567)'s answer for details

Answer (score 16):

Since this question scores high in results, I want to post this preferred alternative:

Oracle has released [APEX 5.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/downloads/index.html) (April 15. 2015). With it you get access to a great API to work with JSON

I'm using it on 11.2 and have been able to crunch every single json, from simple to very complex objects with multiple arrays and 4/5 levels.  [APEX_JSON](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_json.htm#AEAPI29635)

If you do not want to use APEX.  Simply install the runtime environment to get access to the API.

Sample usage, data from [json.org's example](http://json.org/example.html) :

```
declare
    sample_json   varchar2 (32767)
        := '{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}';
begin
    apex_json.parse (sample_json);
    dbms_output.put_line (apex_json.get_varchar2 ('glossary.GlossDiv.title'));
    dbms_output.put_line (apex_json.get_varchar2 ('glossary.GlossDiv.GlossList.GlossEntry.GlossTerm'));
    dbms_output.put_line (apex_json.get_varchar2 ('glossary.GlossDiv.GlossList.GlossEntry.GlossDef.GlossSeeAlso[%d]', 2));
end;
```

Result:
PL/SQL block executed

```
S
Standard Generalized Markup Language
XML
```

Answer (score 1):

Orace provides PL/SQL DOM APIs for JSON handling. Strongly recommend using it, as it provides tons of useful APIs.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ADJSN/using-PLSQL-object-types-for-JSON.htm#GUID-F0561593-D0B9-44EA-9C8C-ACB6AA9474EE

Comment: It is available only stating from Oracle v1.12. Release note: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/plsql-object-types-for-json-12cr2

Answer (score 1):

in Oracle 12:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions092.htm#SQLRF56973

```
SELECT jt.*
FROM j_purchaseorder,
JSON_TABLE(po_document, '$.ShippingInstructions.Phone[*]'
COLUMNS (row_number FOR ORDINALITY,
         phone_type VARCHAR2(10) PATH '$.type',
         phone_num VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.number'))
AS jt;

ROW_NUMBER PHONE_TYPE PHONE_NUM
---------- ---------- --------------------
         1 Office     909-555-7307
         2 Mobile     415-555-1234
```