# Max receiving parameter size in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an APP that sends a JSON to a P/-SQL server. It works until my JSON gets bigger than 32kb, after that the server just gives to my APP:

```
HTTP 400 Value param too long. Length is 36141. Upper limit is 32512
```

My question, it is possible to change this 32kb limit in PL/SQL server or do I have to change my app (which would be a lot of work, more than week)?

Brainstorm, please.

More info about it:

- Android APP that makes a HTTP REQUEST to a PLSQL SERVER.
- Sends a JSON string with lots of parameters. JSON EX:

  ```
  {"key":"b4r5t*a7g954g+5d.f0t","id_usuario":1,"clientes":[{"id_cliente":"1","data_sinc":"2015-10-06 10:33:01"},{"id_cliente":"3","data_sinc":"2015-10-06 10:33:01"},{"id_cliente":"2","data_sinc":"2015-10-06 10:33:01"},{"id_cliente":"29","data_sinc":"2015:10:06 10:33:00"}]}
  ```

It`s not a duplicated from [Store big JSON files into Oracle DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27142161/store-big-json-files-into-oracle-db), I wish it was. My problem is that the server (which is from a client, and I don't really know how it works) is refusing my HTTP access, so it can not concatenate the result, it has any to concatenate.

Comment: Since my answer won't make you happy, I post it merely as a comment: Yes, you probably will have to change your app.

Comment: Anyway, ...
What does it mean "... that sends a JSON to a PL/SQL server" ? What's the client side of the sending routines? What's the server side of the sending routines? What data types are in use on each of the sides? Your question lacks a lot of important information.

Comment: Save the data in a different type?..Clob, Blob?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store big JSON files into Oracle DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27142161/store-big-json-files-into-oracle-db)

Comment: Are you talking about [this mod_plsql limitation](https://community.oracle.com/thread/571638?start=0&tstart=0)? Unfortunately both links are dead. The first link *may* have been for something like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/portal.1111/e12041/concept.htm#YPMOD414). The second link may also be linked to [from this blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/carlback/entry/you_learn_something_new_everyd), but is also dead, and I can't see a current version with a quick search. Good luck.

Comment: Yep, same problem as the first link. But that is from 2007, PL-SQL is the same since?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, seems like there is no way to raise max receiving parameter size in Oracle PL/SQL.

The way around it was to break my string in smaller peaces and have the server top put all the parameters together, and only than make a JSON with it.