# Return results of a sql query as JSON in oracle 11g(in stored procedure)

Tags: json, oracle, performance, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I want to generate a json file from sql query, currently am using **listagg** (modified to handle CLOB data) to form json format., But am feeling its affecting the performance when handling 300 000 rows of data. Is there any inbuilt function or something else which can form json data with less impact on performance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [work with json in oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985841/work-with-json-in-oracle)

Comment: It is wise to do this process in your caller. [Only Oracle 12c has a native support for JSON.](https://www.google.com/search?q=oracle+12c+json&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: PL/JSON is a third-party PL/SQL library for working with JSON. [Find it here](https://github.com/pljson/pljson).  No warranty is offered or implied.