# How do we add values in Json list in Oracle?

Tags: json, database, oracle, sum

An array is being passed form UI in Json, we need to store it in Json list and calculate the sum of integers being stored in the Json list. This has to be implemented in Oracle.

```
IF  j1.exist ('searched_entity')
  THEN
     new_entity:= json_list (j1.get ('searched_entity'));
     .....
     ....
 END LOOP;
END IF;
```

How do I add all the values passed in searched entity?

Answer (score 0):

this may help you out sample for working

Here they did with stored procedure

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985841/work-with-json-in-oracle
```